# JSON Template not displaying

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create JSON template using JS
here is my code.For some reason it doesn't display any result.Can some one please check what is the issue

```
<html>

  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript"src=""http://jsontemplate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascript/json-template.js"">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function write() {
      var t = jsontemplate.Template("{# This is a comment and will be removed from the output.}\n\n{.section products}\n  <h2>Products for Dove</h2>\n\n  <table width=\"100%\">\n  {.repeated section products}\n    <tr><td>{Product Name}</td>\n</tr>\n  {.end}\n  </table>\n{.or}\n  <p><em>(No page content matches)</em></p>\n{.end}\n");
```

`var s = t.expand({`

```
        "products": [{
        "Product Name": "dove moisturiser"


    },


    {
        "Product Name": "Deodrant"

    }]
});
document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML = s;
```

}
        `</script>`
      `</head>`
      `<body onload="write();">`
       `<h4>This is for test.</h4>`
       `<div id="replace"></div>` 
     `</body>` 
   `</html>`

Comment: It seems you have a multiline string, which are not supported in this form in JS. The `src` attribute of the script is wrong too (`src=""http://jsontemplate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascript/json-template.js""`), you need to have only on quotation mark at the beginning and end. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/805107/218196. To learn how to debug JavaScript, have a look at http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners.

Comment: Take your javascript code, open a browser to http://jsfiddle.net/ paste that code in and click the JSHint button.

Comment: I have rectified above errors .and i guess script is triggered but not displaying JSON..any reason.code is updated as above.it is valid in jsfiddle.net